# How to store variable per Http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I am making a very simple nodejs app that used to receive HTTP requests and responses.

In short, is it possible to store a variable globally per HTTP request? So, I don't need to pass that variable anywhere in my application. I know there is `process.env`. However, it is will be overwritten if another request comes simultaneously.

The reason I need this is I wanna have logging for every request. As JavaScript is an async program, it is so confusing when I look at the logging.

For example:

1. Request Received (First Request)
2. Request Received(Second Request)
3. Process result is zzzzzzz
4. Process result is yyyyyyy

So, the process results in Line 4 belong to First or Second Request?

My code sample

```
//In Init.js 
var process = require("process");
http.createServer(function (request, res){
    Console.log("Request Received");
    //Parse the request
    //Generate a unique ID for the requests
    var RequestID = UUID();
    console.log("Request ID is "+ RequestID);  // I don't want to pass this via function parameter as there are so many function involved. 

    process.handler(Request);
}

//In process.js
function handler(Request){
    //do sth with DB / API call and generate the result.
    //the time required is various. 
    console.log("Process result is" + result);
}
```

Comment: I am not good at node js. but normally i solve this by using session. or you can solve it by using Reactive programming for make your code more clean  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the http request context package for what you want to do. Take a look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-request-context

Comment: async hooks, is a neat solution however it can cause a performance problem, see https://dzone.com/articles/beware-the-performance-cost-of-async-hooks-node-8

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have objections to 'polluting' things you don't own, you can always drop the identifier onto the request:

```
http.createServer(function (request, res){
    var requestID = UUID();
    console.log("Request ID is "+ requestID);
    request.requestId = requestID;
    process.handler(request, res);
}
```

and down the line you can pull it off again to use it:

```
myModule.action(request, response, next) {
    console.log("[" + request.requestId + "]: I made it!");
    next();
}
```